# SVN folders from repository

Tags: svn, version-control, repository

In our team we use SVN and after I deleted a project from the solution, cannot delete some of it's folders. When I click commit on the solution this is what shows up:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2RGA.jpg

When try to commit the missing files this is the error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/chbS0.jpg

How should I resolve this problem? Tried to go into the repo-prowser and delete it from there, but was not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Perform `svn revert` operation, to remove the scheduled addition (which was deleted in the meantime).

After `svn revert` is done - perform `svn commit` to publish the changes to the repository.

Comment: Tried reverting, nothing happens.